# Getting a button to shuffle through the timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

How do I get the play head to consecutively go through the timeline containing objects in 4 frames on the click of a button using actionscript 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have a keyframe at each frame.
2. Frame one: add this script

```
stop();
yourButtonName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToNextFrame);
function goToNextFrame(e:Event):void {
   nextFrame();
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's helpful but how do I get it to loop as in go back to first frame and continue

Comment: Compare currentFrame to totalFrames. If you're on the last frame, gotoAndStop(1)